# SQL ORACLE DEVELOPER ALIAS AND ORDER BY

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to do the following query with the alias in lowercase.
Why if I put it in lowercase it gives me an error and in uppercase it works?
Can aliases only be in uppercase?

Code:
`SELECT nombre,poblacion AS "ciudad" FROM clientes ORDER BY ciudad;`

Error:`ORA-00904: "CIUDAD": identificador no válido 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" *Cause:     *Action: Error en la línea: 2, columna: 10`